# What would happen if you were able to shoot a oxygen plasma bead?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electromagnetism, thermodynamics, experimental-physics, physical-chemistry

I was curious about the effects a bead of superheated oxygen (to the point of a plasma state) would have not the air and nearby spectators. It is my understanding that the temperature required to create a oxygen plasma is near 12000 Kelvin, but would a small bead of it appear to be a raging ball of fire? How much heat would a spectator feel from 10-20 feet away, and how long would the bead be able to travel before converting back into a gas? Also would the bead of oxygen be heavy, requiring a large number of oxygen molecules in its plasma state?